# Derive union type from another union type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a union type like this:

```
{id: 'A', format: 'foo' | 'bar, value: 1 | 2} 
  | 
{id: 'B', format: 'baz', value: 3 | 4} 
  | 
{id: 'C', format: 'qux', value: 'hello' | 'goodbye'}
```

I want each object of this type to keep its internal relations so that if `id` equals `A`, format must be `foo` or `bar`, etc.

Now, I want to create another type which is related to `Entry`, and which has the same `id` property, but `format` is optional and `value` should be omitted. Let's call it `EntryInput` (imagine a function where you supply an `EntryInput` as input parameter and get back a `Entry`).
But I don't want to define this type from scratch again - instead I want to create it from the `Entry` type. However, as soon as you apply e.g. `Pick` on a union like this, all properties are mixed together to form `{id: 'A' | 'B' | 'C'; format: 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz' | 'qux'; value: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 'hello' | 'goodbye'}`. See for example https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28339

I know that I can create a generic type `Entry<Id extends 'A' | 'B' | 'C'>` and create a function like `createEntry<Id>(input: EntryInput<Id>): Entry<Id>` to maintain the relation between input type and output type for the function, and where `Id` is inferred from the supplied value, hence forcing `format` to properly relate to `id`, but what I need is not a generic type, I need a union type so that I can e.g. declare

```
const entries: Entry[] = [ ... ]
```

... and each entry here is consistent so that the value of `id` decides the possible values of `format` and `value`. If doing that with a generic type, the properties will once again be distributed so that `{id: 'A', format: 'qux', value: 'hello}` is a valid `Entry`.

How can I set up my types so that I can derive types `EntryInput` from `Entry` while keeping the internal relations between properties intact?

Comment: What is a "distributed union type"?  That's not a conventional term; do you mean *discriminated* union?

Comment: Another terminology issue; you say you have a “mapped type” but I don’t see a mapped type there; you can’t map a union to a tuple so maybe you mean you just… wrote a new type?  Not sure what the use of `Entries` is either; does that tuple ordering mean something to you? If not then you should remove it and just use `Entry`

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/ND8pRN) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (but please [edit] the question to fix the issues mentioned in my previous comments); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry for my bad terminology, I read several posts and issues about distributing keys over unions etc and probably got terms mixed up. Your solution seems to work, but I did come up with a solution myself as well. I did start out with a mapped type, but changed to the array type solution, and this is what got me off track I believe.
Please go ahead and post your solution as an answer, I will post mine as an alternative. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the question; given your own answer I now understand that you started with an `EntryMap` type and derived both `Entry` and `EntryInput` from it by distributing a type operation over the union of properties, but that information wasn't really present in the question so there's no plausible way someone other than you could have answered it that way.  I've changed it to just ask the straightforward "derive `EntryInput` from `Entry`" version; hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the following [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
type Entry =
  { id: 'A', format: 'foo' | 'bar', value: 1 | 2 } |
  { id: 'B', format: 'baz', value: 3 | 4 } |
  { id: 'C', format: 'qux', value: 'hello' | 'goodbye' }
```

we can create a new union of the desired form by operating on it with a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) as follows:

```
type EntryInput = Entry extends infer E ?
  E extends { id: infer I, format: infer F } ? { id: I, format?: F } : never
  : never;

/* type EntryInput = 
   { id: "A"; format?: "foo" | "bar" | undefined; } | 
   { id: "B"; format?: "baz" | undefined; } | 
   { id: "C"; format?: "qux" | undefined; } 
*/
```

Conditional types only distribute over unions if the type being checked is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, and `Entry` is not a generic.  If you tried `Entry extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : never` it wouldn't distribute.  The `Entry2` definition uses a little trick with [conditional type `infer`ence](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to "copy" `Entry` into a generic type parameter `E` so that the check `E extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : never` is indeed distributive.

(If that trick is too weird you can refactor into something like

```
type EntryInputHelper<E> =
  E extends { id: infer I, format: infer F } ? { id: I, format?: F } : never
type EntryInput = EntryInputHelper<Entry>;
```

where you create a generic type function just to use it exactly once.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiKBeAUFKBvKBLAEwC4oByAQVIBooAzAe0QFsBDYE0h+0qAHzIBGLRNSgA3FgBsArhBIBGPlABMUAL59MOfMTIAhUQ2ZsOQgF6iJMuVADMSgCzrNWXIQ4BhQ41bsyAR2kAD0spWQ4ACwhJSW4lUgBzenoCARAIHjV0dFBIWARkAEk4MGlgNHykFAgg4Ag4AgBnfDhaCERYKAB+LRgoGrqG5rddPFb2qEKaI18SMbaOgDFnLu13SemfNi6SZY0SOAgxdq0Do-aAbmyAegAqKFzoeCri0vLUKC013QAich+LnQtsAdlAflwfkofkJEJD+NIGhBaGMIARARp+F8RiQfnoAUDjCCceY4VAEQQkSi0c5MVhvjiPPiZtscYEgqTyZTDtSNOhbtdso9KkUSmUABLRSCIAA8MAAfGhev1avUmvSWgsNgTZhqJntuuqptqWVB9WdjogcuAngUQK8yqoPs8RW8JZIpbLbXKLkA)

Answer (score 0):

My own solution ended up like this. What I needed was a map of id to {format, value} to derive the other types from using mapped types, which will distribute over keys:

```
/**
 * This is just an internal type building the possible combinations, which the actual types will derive from
 */
type EntryMap = {
  A: {format: 'foo' | 'bar', value: 1 | 2},
  B: {format: 'baz', value: 3 | 4},
  C: {format: 'qux', value: 'hello' | 'goodbye'},
}

/**
 * Possible values for 'id'
 */
export type EntryId = keyof EntryMap;

/**
 * Combine id: 'A' | 'B' | 'C' with the properties of A, B or C, respectively, distributing over 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
 */
export type Entry<K extends EntryId = EntryId> = {
  [P in K]: {id: P} & EntryMap[P];
}[K];

/**
 * Combine id: 'A' | 'B' | 'C' with the optional format property of A, B or C, respectively, distributing over 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
 */
export type EntryInput<K extends EntryId = EntryId> = {
  [P in K]: {id: P} & Partial<Pick<EntryMap[P], 'format'>>;
}[K];

// tests
const e1: Entry = {id: 'A', format: 'foo', value: 1}; // OK
const e2: Entry = {id: 'A', format: 'baz', value: 1}; // FAILS as expected - format 'baz' is not allowed for an Entry with id: 'A'
const e3: Entry<'B'> = {id: 'B', format: 'baz', value: 4}; // OK
const i1: EntryInput = {id: 'A', format: 'bar'} // OK
const i2: EntryInput = {id: 'A', format: 'qux'} // FAILS as expected
```